# Xerox Workcentre 3119 and Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, printer, cups

I'm trying to get Xerox Workcentre 3119 printer to work on Linux. It's a multifunction device (printer and scanner). I run the CUPS web interface at:

http://localhost:631/

and it recognizes it on USB port and even suggests Gutenprint driver from the list. When I try to print a test page, the printer goes through "warming up" process (i.e. lights blink and sound is heard) but does not print anything.

There are no errors in /var/log/cups/error_log and access_log shows as if everything is ok.

The printer works fine in Windows XP.

Does anyone have any experience with this printer on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu, the solution is very simle. 
You need to install the following driver:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-splix
```

Once the driver has been installed you can choose Xerox WorkCentre 3119 on web interface of CUPS from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try another driver, probably a different postscript driver.

Xerox also distributes PPD files for many of their printers--but in general Xerox printers tend to support PostScript and a generic postscript driver will work.

Answer (score 0):

Xerox Workcentres--at least the ones in my office (5645)--usually have a feature to show print jobs and their status on the machine, and it might provide you with some meaningful troubleshooting.

It took me hours of troubleshooting to get ours to work with linux, but the biggest problem was the User Standard Accounting feature; even the drivers on the Xerox website didn't work properly with user accounting. I ended up re-writing parts of the driver (.ppd file) to manage the accounting. I recount the procedure and post the driver I used (--similar methods might work for you model--) [in this thread on the Ubuntu forums.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9556354#post9556354) Good luck!